# Edit Tabview Background Color

Tags: android

how should i change the background color of tab in android TabActivity
this is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

}
```

`

Comment: Not a solution, just an implementation detail but consider designing your app with ActionBar tabs instead of the old (and deprecated) TabActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and you want to change the color of the tabhost, not the view that loads when you tap a tab, you can do it like this

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer basically i need to do both of things.